# The set of 2x2 matrices with determinant 1 is a vector subspace of the vector space of all real 2x2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of 2x2 matrices with determinant 1 is a vector subspace of the vector space of all real 2x2 matrices?
Is this statement true or false?

Comment: Vector spaces need zero elements, right?

Comment: It is not a vector space, but it is a group. Moreover it is a normal subgroup of the group of all invertible matrices.

Answer (score 0):

False as the zero matrix has determinant zero and a vector space must contain the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

> It is  group multiplication not vector space.

Indeed that subspace is not closed under additivity.